# How i can select a specific value from json in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What I'm trying to get is to select the "url" value of the "quality" is hd720

**Component**

```
    componentDidMount() {

       return fetch('https://you-link.herokuapp.com/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGCLs9Bt_KY')
         .then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
           this.setState({
             isLoading: false,
             dataSource: responseJson,
             videoUrl: responseJson[0].url
           }, function() {
           });
         })
         .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });
     }
```

**Json Call**
[Link](https://you-link.herokuapp.com/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGCLs9Bt_KY)

Comment: I don't see anything inherently wrong with your request. What is the error?

Comment: You can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find): `responseJson.find(obj => obj.quality === "hd720").url`

Comment: I've tried the code but it does not work: "responseJson.find is not a function"

Comment: Try the following block of code

Comment: @bdroid, if responseJson.find does not exist, then you need to debug the response before.

.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
})

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to search the JSON Array with the matching condition ([Using find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find))
in this case "quality" === "hd720"

```
componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://you-link.herokuapp.com/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGCLs9Bt_KY')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            let url = responseJson.find(obj => obj.quality === "hd720").url
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                dataSource: responseJson,
                videoUrl: url
            }, function() {});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: My Pleasure. Happy coding.